# Bug in RichTextBox font color when appending Null character

Tags: c#, .net, richtextbox

I have an application (developed in C#, .Net 2.0, VS 2010 SP1) that reads/writes to the serial port and and puts the communication on a RichTextBox control. I have been asked to color code the contents based on the direction (whether they are incoming or outgoing) and mark where there are control characters (kind of similar to RealTerm when they show which control character is in the message). therefore in a method when there is a control character I add <> tag. when I want to update my RTF using the string from the aforementioned method, I look for '<' and '>' and change the color of the text. However, if the character to be added is 0x00 or null after  tag, when I call the .append method of RTB, the fontcolor switches to what it was before and therefore the string after  gets the same color as the tag.

I have already found a work around for this issue by changing the color after the append method but this seemed very curious to me. I reviewed many online discussions/questions on this website and MSDN but nobody has addressed this and read RichTextbox documentation. Am I missing something obvious? Or is this just another VS issue?

this is the method that determines the color and appends the characters to the RTB:

```
private void FormatAndAddText(string text_, bool isRx_)
{
    RichTextBox.DeselectAll(); //If I dont call this method, If the user has selected the some text, the starred line will change the font color of the selection

    Color mainTextColor = (isRx_ ? Color.LawnGreen : Color.Yellow);
    Color tagsTextColor = (isRx_ ? Color.Red : Color.Blue);

    RichTextBox.SelectionColor = mainTextColor; //****this will modify the color of the text, if user has selected some of it.

    for(int i = 0; i< text_.Length; i++)
    {
        char char = text_[i];

        if (_char == '<')
            RichTextBox.SelectionColor = tagsTextColor ;

        RichTextBox.AppendText(char.ToString()); //if char is 0x00, the color resets!!!

        if ((i < text_.Length-1))
        {
            if (char == '>')
                RichTextBox.SelectionColor = mainTextColor; //change the color to what it is supposed to be.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Writing NULL when you get the 0x00 is not an option?

Comment: @Steve, I write the null but when they review the logs, they want to know that there was a null char somewhere, so when I receive [0x31][0x32][0x33][0x00][0x31][0x32][0x33], I add: 123<NUL>[the actual null char]123

Comment: I am not aware of problems with the RTB with special characters, but if this \0 char is proving to be difficult I was suggesting to insert a special sequence of characters that represent the null value. Something like  `[0x31][NULL][0x32]`

Comment: @Steve
Well to preserve the authenticity (not loosing any data), I set the color again, after I append the char, but I was just curious to know if this is me or something is not quite right on RTB.

Comment: `DeselectAll();` is a void.  How does this compile: `RichTextBox.DeselectAll.SelectionColor = mainTextColor;`?

Comment: @LarsTech, Thanks for the note actually I made a mistake when changing my code's parameters name...Now it should be fixed.